# Mass of quantum fluctuations in space?

Tags: space

I have no formal training in physics, just a casual interest, so if this question doesn't make sense i would love to understand why.

I know from casual physics talks etc that pairs of particles pop in and out of existence due to fluctuations in the underlying relevant field.

Does that mean that for every instant there is an extra amount of mass per unit of space equal to the massive 'fluctuation' particles that still did not pop out of existence/annihilate?

If that holds true has anyone measured it or calculated it?

Comment: I think this question is more apt for the physics SE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i will repost on physics SE as soon as i get a chance. Should i remove this one though?

Comment: The particles consume the equivalent amount of energy, so there is no conservation problem.

Comment: @olokki ... I am also extremely interested in this, but alas am not an expert (you know how they say that sometimes a little bit of knowledge is dangerous). I'm hoping that one day in the distant future this can be used for space travel (I'm told that would violate the second law of thermodynamics). One tidbit of info that might help is that these "virtual particles" that pop in and out of existence exist for such a short period of time that they are impossible to measure (ie. less than 10E-15 sec).

Comment: Also, there is a HUGE discrepancy between what quantum field theory predicts for the energy that permeates all of space and what is seen in the form of dark energy. (I think that it is supposed to be this energy that produces the "virtual particles".) In other words, scientists don't truly understand this, which gives us a tiny bit of hope for exploiting this phenomenon in the future.